# File locked in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: permissions, files

I recently decided it was a good idea to start using Ubuntu again, I can access all my files on my Windows partition and such but I can only open in read only. Every time, WPS Office gives me this message: "Document has been locked by crackers. Do you want to open it as read-only?" Crackers is my username BTW, it is also different from my Windows username if that is helpful.

How would I be able to change the permissions of this file? In the properties it says the owner is root. Also I don't want to just copy my files because windows can't read EXT4 (I think thats what it is) and I dont want to have to hassle with a USB.

UPDATE: I have tried disabling fast startup and using `chmod` to edit permissions.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that windows lock down its stuff before shutting down as in general **fastboot** is enabled.

- Fastboot is just a feature in windows, which let it store certain cache files to help in fast startup.
- In exchange leaving all your windows files in read mode only.
- When this feature is on you might have observed that windows come back to same state as it was when you shut it down (means if you left some files open, they will open up at startup).

So the problem you are facing of not being able to edit files can be solved by disabling **Fastboot**. *It is completely harmless to disable this feature.*

**How to disable Fastboot** :- pretty easy.

- Just follow this [Link](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup).
- And if you don't want to disable it that then while clicking on shutdown in windows keep shift key pressed down (it will disable fastboot for that specific instance).

**Ownership Issue**
To change the ownership of the file use command

- For a single file, and directory

  `sudo chown user:user filename/directory`
- For directory and all content in it

  `sudo chown -R user:user directory_name`

Former 'user' in `user:user` is for the owner and latter one is for the group, replace `user` with your username in actual implementation. You can leave the part after colon, code will look like-
`sudo chown -R user directory_name`. `-R` means apply this to the directory recursively, in simple apply to all folders/subfolders/files.

Comment: Saw this on many websites regarding this question, but it still gives me this.(Link in post)

Comment: I replace >user with my username right?

Comment: Wait I think I realized something. It says the file has been locked by myself. Would somehow unlocking the file solve the problem? Using text editor I am able to edit text  documents in the same folder. Also it seems to just be those two files now... all other ppts and docs work. thanks for the help

Comment: yes ofcourse, changing ownership will automatically unlock the file for you. Or there is one more way to change ownership, i will update that in answer